# Joining multiple adjacent members of a list up until a max length

Tags: python

I want to join multiple adjacent members of a list up until a max length.

I know how to do it if is just two (with zip), but I'm searching for a solution to do it using a variable length.

Example:

```
list: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
max_len = 3.
```

Result:

```
ab
bc
abc
cd
bcd
de
cde
ef
def
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with slicing lists before passing it on.

```
maxlen=10
newlist1=list1[:maxlen]
newlist2=list2[:maxlen]
```